# E java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.nitgen.SDK.AndroidBSP.NBioBSPJNI

Tags: java, android

The app does not crash but the app freezes for a few seconds whenever the below log comes up. How to fix

Uncaught exception is thrown by finalizer
10:22:54.997  E  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.nitgen.SDK.AndroidBSP.NBioBSPJNI$1@b70d041

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication\MainActivity.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
^
symbol:   variable fab
location: variable appBarMain of type AppBarMainBinding

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).